# Django template jinja for loop

Tags: django, templates, jinja2

Can someone suggest me how to iterate a dictionary in django template?

```
dic1={5: ['jaw replacement - 23-Jun-2020 (16:20:09.164240)', 'jaw replacement done - 23-Jun-2020 (16:20:51.158085)', 'jaw replacement done,almost done - 23-Jun-2020 (16:25:40.066955)', 'jaw replacement done,almost done 1 - 23-Jun-2020 (16:27:00.355605)', 'jaw replacement done,almost done 2 - 23-Jun-2020 (16:31:35.111660)']}

this is the context i am passing
i need something like this in template
for i in dic1:
    print(i)
    list1=dic1[i]
    for k in list1:
        print(k)

{% for i in notes %}
          {% with list1=dic1[i] %}
            {{list1}}
          {% endwith %}

      {% endfor %}
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass dic1 one directly to the template from view and iterate through dictionary in template \

in view

```
return render(request, 'template.html',{'dic1':dic1})
```

```
#intemplate.html

{% for key, value in dic1 %}
    <tr>
        <td> Key: {{ key }} </td>
      {% for value_in_array in value %}
         <td> Value: {{ value }} </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your data is -

```
dic1 = {'a': [ [1, 2] ], 'b': [ [3, 4] ],'c':[ [5,6]] }
```

You can use the `data.items()` method to get the dictionary elements. Note, in django templates we do NOT put `()`. Also some users mentioned values`[0]` does not work, if that is the case then try `values.items`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>

    {% for key, values in dic1.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        {% for v in values[0] %}
        <td>{{v}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I hope It helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In normal Python you would normally access keys and values by using the items() method on a dictionaty.

For example given the dictionary

```
some_dic = {'1': 'Hello', '2': 'World'}
```

You should be able to access this by doing the following:

```
for key, value in some_dic.items():
    print(key, value)
```

You can follow this same principle in Django templates and simply omit the '()' as follows:

```
{% for key, value in some_dic.items %}
    <h1>Key: {{ key }}</h1>
    <h1>Value: {{ value }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```